# LibGDX - check if compass needs calibration

Tags: libgdx, compass-geolocation, calibration

How to check if compass is calibrated well in LibGDX (on Android). I've found how to do it on native Android:

[In Android can I programmatically detect that the compass is not yet calibrated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099568/in-android-can-i-programmatically-detect-that-the-compass-is-not-yet-calibrated)

But couldn't find if that's implemented in LibGDX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is described in the wiki article [Interfacing with platform specific code](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code). LibGDX doesn't have any functionality for it because it isn't common and it doesn't make any sense for other backends.

In the `core` module you'll have something like this:

```java
public interface GameListener {
    void calibrateCompassIfNeeded()
}

public class Application extends ApplicationAdapter {

    private GameListener listener;    

    public Application(GameListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void create() {
        // Call listener.calibrateCompassIfNeeded() whenever needed.
    }

    public void onCompassChanged(float[] values) {
        // Do something...
    }
}
```

And in the `android` module:

```java
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements GameListener, SensorEventListener {
    private static final int COMPASS_ACCURACY_UNKNOWN = -1;

    private Application app;
    private int compassAccuracy = COMPASS_ACCURACY_UNKNOWN;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
        super.onCreate(state);

        SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        Sensor compassSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, compassSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME)

        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        app = new Application(this);
        initialize(app, config);
    }

    @Override
    public void calibrateCompassIfNeeded() {
        if (compassAccuracy != COMPASS_ACCURACY_UNKNOWN && compassAccuracy < SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_MEDIUM) {
            // Calibrate only if accuracy is below medium.
            // Show whatever is needed so user calibrates the compass.
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
            app.onCompassChanged(event.values);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
       compassAccuracy = accuracy;
    }
}
```

I haven't tried it and I have never used the compass before but I'm pretty sure this will work fine.

Comment: If compass reading is "common and makes sense for other platforms" then checking if that same compass is calibrated well or not should also be.